# EFCore - How to run simple query on a loop?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a project where users can queue up actions to happen in the future. Each future action is saved in the database. I'm trying to find a way to get all the actions that have already passed and act on them. Currently I'm doing this:

```cs
public class TaskingManager
{
    private static readonly System.Timers.Timer RefreshEventsLoop = new(1000);

    public void Initialize()
    {
        RefreshEventsLoop.Elapsed += RefreshEventsLoop_Elapsed;
        RefreshEventsLoop.AutoReset = false;
        RefreshEventsLoop.Start();
    }

    private void RefreshEventsLoop_Elapsed(object? sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshEventsLoop.Enabled = false;
        ProcessEventsQueue();
        RefreshEventsLoop.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void ProcessEventsQueue()
    {
        var timeNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var context = new GalaxyDbContext(_dbOptions);
        var dbFunctions = new DatabaseFunctions(context);

        var eventsToProcess = context.FutureEvents
            .Where(futureEvent => futureEvent.TriggerTime <= timeNow)
            .ToList();

        if (eventsToProcess.Any())
        {
            context.FutureEvents.RemoveRange(eventsToProcess);
            context.SaveChanges();
            
            foreach (var pastEvent in eventsToProcess)
            {
                _messageMap[pastEvent.MessageType].Invoke(dbFunctions).Execute(pastEvent);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dbFunctions.CreateFutureScienceTask();
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work ok. But the problem is that after the app has been running for a while, I can see the LINQ part is taking up a huge amount of memory:
[524MB used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Evz.png)

And if I leave it running for a few days then it's up in the gigs.

I'm guessing running this query every second is wasteful on resources. But I don't know of a better way to do this. Is there a way to continuously check the database for something like this?

Comment: At least you have to dispose context: `using var context = new GalaxyDbContext(_dbOptions);`

Comment: If your trigger time is in minutes, you can check every minute instead of every second.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing i can see is that you are not disposing the databasecontextt afer you used it.
Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/) for more info about entityframework context lifetime.

To properly dispose it use a using statement.

```
using (var context = new GalaxyDbContext(_dbOptions))
{
    //your code that uses the context
}
```

Or with new using syntax:

```
using (var context = new GalaxyDbContext(_dbOptions));
//your code that uses the context
```

Right know the problem could be that you create a context everytime you call the function and never dispose it and it still keeps references to the data etc..

Comment: Interesting tip, thanks for that. How come the context stays around though? I would have thought that when ProcessEventsQueue() ends it would get garbage collected like every other variable in that scope. Are DbContexts special?

Comment: Depending on your code, it might not. The documentation says _It is very important to dispose the DbContext after use. This ensures both that any unmanaged resources are freed, and that any events or other hooks are unregistered so as to prevent memory leaks in case the instance remains referenced._